# Why did this trivial rm -rf command destroy my operating system?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, path, rm, variable-substitution

I use Bash 4.3.48(1) and I ran the following command pattern on a testing VPS machine:

```
rm -rf ${drt}/${pma}*
```

This command deleted the entire operating system (Ubuntu). That was evident by executing `cd /` which returned nothing but the following error:

> bash: cd /: No such file or directory

In a deeper look, this happened because both variables in the original command above, were not declared:

1. I created a file named `~/repoName/assignments_variables.sh` that contains a list of exported variables (including `drt` and `pma`).
2. Instead running `source /etc/bash.bashrc`, I ran `/etc/bash.bashrc`, which was wrong, because that file is only relevant to the current session (though it can be used to subsequently run files that by themselves execute data in subsessions).

---

Now that it's clear to me that the bad path is the general cause for the problem, I'd like to dive a bit deeper and ask this:

Why did the `rm -rf` ignored the wrong variable-expansions and kept going to the `/*`? I know that `rm -rf` should delete a dir **only** if it finds it, hence shouldn't rely on parts of the path of a non-existent dir (like `/*` that caused deletion of the operating system). How could I improve the `rm -rf` command to cover possible similar cases of a bad path (due to wrong variable-expansions) in the future?

Is there some Bash directive to make sure that Bash will never expand empty variables (until I undo that directive)?

---

<sub>Let me emphasize: I usually work not only with backups but with double backups. That was really a testing environment with x3 backups in background.</sub>

Comment: I published a similar question but deleted it. User: jesse_b commented there. I'd like jesse to read this one. Can someone tag jesse_b somehow? Thanks.

Comment: `/*` is `/bin /boot /dev /etc /home /lib /lib64 /lost+found /media /mnt /opt /proc /root /run /sbin /srv /sys /tmp /usr /var`, not a non-existent directory.

Comment: @user9303970:  Sorry I had just noticed a syntax error in your previous question but as Michael Homer and isaac pointed out, it looks like you actually have wiped your system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As has been pointed out, the two variables `drt` and `pma` were not present in your script's environment, which meant that the shell expanded these to empty strings.  The resulting command was `rm -rf /*` (with `*` further expanded to whatever was available in the root directory).

The root directory itself will not be removed by running `rm -rf /*` as root. Also, I (and [Jesse_b](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/237982/jesse-b) who pointed it out to me) am slightly confused by the error message

```
bash: cd /: No such file or directory
```

The only way I'm able to provoke this error message myself is by running the command `"cd /"` (note the quotation marks).  Had `/` really been removed, the error message would have said

```
bash: cd: /: No such file or directory
```

[isaac has already given some tips](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/423336/116858) for how to prevent you from doing things like this in the future, but I thought that I'd just chip in with my awn advice.

- Don't work at a root shell prompt.
- If writing scripts that requires root permissions, use `sudo` in the script on the *specific* commands that actually require these elevated permissions. Don't run the whole script as root, *especially* not during development.
- You usually do not need to touch `/etc/bash.bashrc` for any reason, and you should never have to explicitly source it. Environment variables can be created in

  - a user's own `$HOME/.bashrc` (if the script is to be run from an interactive session), or
  - in the script itself, or
  - in a separate file (written *for* the script) sourced by the script explicitly, or
  - in a file pointed to by the `BASH_ENV` environment variable.

Another safety measure that would have saved you in this case is running your script under `set -u` (`nounset`) and possibly also `set -e` (`errexit`).  The `nounset` shell option will threat the expansion of an unset variable as an error while the `errexit` shell option will exit the shell session immediately if a command exits with a non-zero exit status.

The script

```
#!/bin/bash -ue

echo "$hello"
echo "world"
```

will never output `world` but will instead provoke the message

```
script.sh: line 3: hello: unbound variable
```

before terminating.  (It's the `-u` that does the terminating, `-e` is doesn't do anything *in this simple example*).

Answer (score 5):

What is expanded if the variables don't exist?
Let's try (note the echo):

```
$ unset drt pma
$ echo rm -rf ${drt}/${pma}*
rm -rf /bin /boot /dev /etc /hello /home /initrd.img /lib /lib32 /lib64 /libx32 /media /mnt /opt /proc /root /run /sbin /srv /sys /tmp /usr /var /vmlinuz /vmlinuz.old
```

that is the whole system (as you have already confirmed).
The problem is the expansion done by the shell.

## prevention

How do we prevent that from happening?
By preventing the shell from expanding empty variables.
The expansion of `${var:?message}` yields `message` if var is empty or unset.
**And** stops execution (critical error). Test it:

```
$ echo rm -rf "${drt:?Missing variable drt}"/"${pma:?Missing variable pma}"*
```

And this solution is POSIX compatible.

Comment: Not running as root also helps a bit.

Answer (score 2):

Variables not set interpolate to nothing so what was run was the glob `rm -rf /*` which is all things under `/` which is bad as you found out.

Add error checking. And, also, quote the `"$variables"` because otherwise the shell does a split-glob on them and then stupid things can happen when the `$variables` contain a space or other problematical characters. Especially when a `rm -rf` is involved.

```
if [[ -z "$drt" ]]; then
    echo >&2 "drt variable not set ??"
    exit 1
fi
if [[ -z "$pma" ]]; then
    echo >&2 "pma variable not set ??"
    exit 1
fi
rm -rf "${drt}"/"${pma}"*
```

(Or use a less problematical language for programming in...)

Comment: I'd use a function to reduce the tedious boilerplate code repetition.  e.g. `error() { ec="$1"; shift; echo >&2 "$@" ; exit "$ec" ; }`.   Then: `[ -z "$drt" ] && error 1 "drt variable not set ??"`.   Also there's no need to quote the variables separately.  The `*` wildcard needs to be outside of the quoted string so that the shell can expand it, but the two variables can be in one quoted string.  e.g. `"${drt}/${pma}"*` or just  `"$drt/$pma"*`

Comment: @cas that's what I do in other languages; anything that complicated I do not write in `sh`

Comment: to me, that's a way of reducing the complexity (or at least the visual complexity) of a script.  and shorten it, from 4 lines per test to 1 line.